# Wrong horizontal spacing of tabular in KOMA-script firsthead

Tags: horizontal-alignment, koma-script

I am trying to replicate my company's corporate design Word template in LaTeX and getting stuck with this behavior:
I defined a `firsthead`

```
\setkomavar{firsthead}{
    \scriptsize
    test\\
    \begin{tabular}[b]{p{57.5mm}}
        ttest
    \end{tabular}
}
```

and placed it at`\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{142.5mm}`.
Now `test` starts at approx 142.5mm from the left edge of the paper while `ttest` has an unintended extra horizontal spacing:
[image: horizontal spacing]
The issue also occurs with minibox or parbox and is independent of the actual width of the tabular/minipage.

If I use `\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{57.5mm}}` which removes the column spacing (I think), the horizontal shift turns to the opposite direction:

[image: with @{}]

MWE-Code:

```
\documentclass[]{scrlttr2}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{142.5mm}
\makeatother
\setkomavar{firsthead}{
    \scriptsize
        test\\
        \begin{tabular}[b]{p{57.5mm}}
        ttest
        \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Test}
\opening{Hi}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{head}
```

to visualize the position of the header.

Your code adds a spurious space before "text". You have to comment the line end after `\setkomavar{firsthead}{` to remove this spurious space.

The horizontal space before "ttest" is the `tabcolsep` in the first column of the table. To remove this horizontal space use `@{}` before `p{57.5mm}`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrlttr2}

\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{head}% visualize the position of the first header

\setplength{firstheadhpos}{142.5mm}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{% <- comment the line end to remove the spurious space
    \scriptsize
        test\\
        \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{57.5mm}@{}}% <- changed
        ttest
        \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Test}
\opening{Hi}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Remark: With an uptodate KOMA-Script version you can replace `\@setplength` by `\setplength`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works! :-)
I tried the `@{}`, but I would never have thought about the uncommented line end...

Comment: What is the difference between `\@setplength` and `\setplength`?

Comment: `\setplength` can be used in the document preamble without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. So it is now a user command.